# How to validate token in Azure AD with Python

Tags: python, azure, adal

1. I have registered two apps following this [Azure AD demo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon) from step1 to step 4.
2. And I git cloned [Azure AD demo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-python-webapp-graphapi) and ran it successfully.
3. But I want to request my custom API, so I replace the `resource`,but i get something wrong. The resource URI appears like `http://<talent-id>/TodoListDaemon`.

Now, I have two questions:

1. How do I set up a true resource?
2. How extra work in my custom api