# How Can I get an ID Token while validating using Username and Password?

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am using Python ADAL library to Authenticate a user using Azure Active Directory. I successfully receive the access token post authentication. Now, I want to verify the validity of the access token. I need the ID_TOKEN in this case. How do I get it?

```py
import adal
auth_context = adal.AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}")
token_response = auth_context.acquire_token_with_username_password("https://management.core.windows.net/", username, password, client_id)
```

In the token response, I get the access_token and refresh_token but I do not receive the id_token. Following a similar question, [How to verify JWT id_token produced by MS Azure AD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142716/how-to-verify-jwt-id-token-produced-by-ms-azure-ad#) I used the code to validate the access token but I need the ID_TOKEN.

Any thoughts on getting this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

No need to get the `ID_TOKEN`, try the code as below.

```
import adal
import jwt

auth_context = adal.AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}")
token_response = auth_context.acquire_token_with_username_password("https://management.core.windows.net/", username, password, client_id)

token_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token_response['accessToken'])
```

For more details, you could refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51964173/how-to-validate-token-in-azure-ad-with-python) and this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens).

Comment: I tried this. It does work, however even if I add some random values to the token it still sends me back those headers. Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: @RoshanJoeVincent How did you do? Maybe this issue?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869775/access-token-validation-in-azure-ad-authentication/57870035#57870035